# Nested print in a nested loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

How can I create outputs created in two for loops?

What I would like to have:

```
Name1
Adress1

Name2
Adress2

..
```

What I get:

```
Name1
Name2

Adress1
Adress2
```

I have already tried a lot and brought back to the initial situation.

The names and the adresses are parsed from a HTML document, and written with the for loops into a txt file. (in the first step to the console)

I thank you in advance!

```
    with urllib.request.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/test.html") as url:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
        for name in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "name m08_name" }):
            print(name.get_text())
        for adress in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "adresse m08_adresse" }): 
            print(adress.get_text())
```

Comment: `for name,address in zip(soup.findAll(...), soup.findAll(...))`

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Good answer, but you really should have put it into an actual answer so it could be voted, accepted, etc. I'll give you a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to save your partial results and then zip them togheter.

Note that you have to be sure that the number of names is exactly equal to the number of addresses.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/test.html") as url:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

    names = [name.get_text() for name in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "name m08_name" })]
    addresses = [address.get_text() for adress in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "adresse m08_adresse" })]
    for line in zip(names, addresses):
        print("%s\n%s" % line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Its new staff for me , this "zip" ;)